# spring cloud dataflow kafka binder error on sending - Magic v1 does not support record headers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Trying to get spring cloud data flow stream work in Kubernetes and Getting  below error  when the Source  try to send message to kafka. The same code worked fine when i used Rabbit MQ.Kafka  Server version   Kafka 2.1.0  . I read in other posts that this could be due to kafka version incompatibility with the client bundled with a lower kafka version .Wondering how can i get this working.

**CODE For SENDING MESSAGE TO THE KAFKA CHANNEL**

```
   public  void sendToChannelNew(List<String> list,String name)  {        
        MessageBuilder builder=MessageBuilder.withPayload(list.toString());
        builder=builder.setHeader("SOURCE",name);
        source.output().send(builder.build());
    }
```

**POM**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@5a4a522a]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[271962], headers={SOURCE=CLIENT
entType=application/json, timestamp=1574199924374}]' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@5
ArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[271962], headers={SOURCE=ACCOUNT_CLIENT, id=2dcee73c-9da0-72fe-d5f7-07a2dba5b099, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1574199924374}]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@5a4a522a]; nested exception is java.lang.Il
rt record headers
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:179)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1077)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
        at com.jpmorgan.awm.wm.edpipoc.EdpiSource.sendToChannelNew(EdpiSource.java:73)
        at com.jpmorgan.awm.wm.edpipoc.EdpiSource.lambda$null$2(EdpiSource.java:134)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:73)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRunnable.call(MonoRunnable.java:32)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:225)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.ImmediateScheduler.schedule(ImmediateScheduler.java:47)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOnCallable.subscribe(MonoSubscribeOnCallable.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3694)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:244)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBuffer$BufferExactSubscriber.onComplete(FluxBuffer.java:183)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:248)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextStart.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262)
        at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postCompleteDrain(DrainUtils.java:131)
        at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postComplete(DrainUtils.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onComplete(FluxBufferPredicate.java:285)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:325)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:638)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFlattenIterable.java:259)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:372)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:196)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:337)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:334)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:381)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:522)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:141)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1436)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1203)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1247)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:799)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:427)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:328)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.appendWithOffset(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:449)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:506)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecordsBuilder.append(MemoryRecordsBuilder.java:529)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.tryAppend(ProducerBatch.java:107)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:223)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:864)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:444)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:372)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:209)
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:382)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right Kafka cluster? That error indeed is an indication of a version mismatch. Please make sure that you are using a Kafka broker that is compatible with supporting headers. From Kafka brokers 0.11 and up, it should support headers.

Comment: While 0.11 supports headers, it is still very old; the current version is 2.3.1; you should upgrade to as new a version of the broker as possible.

Comment: Thanks Soby & Gary,  sorry my bad the version is  0.10.0-kafka2.1.0  , Please suggest Is there  a way to get this working with out upgrading the kaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with kakfka broker used  was old (0.10.0)  not supporting headers  .switched to a higher version and got this fixed

Comment: Hi @Ajith Kannan! How do you change that?

Comment: I was using kafka broker 0.10.0 . So upgraded the kafka library to a higher version.